How can I manually modify the scope from a accessToken JWT
I m super new with mobile development and swift, so if my question is stupid pardon me.
Now I'm trying to make a login with AWSCognito, after the check in a user pool, the user is logged in and after that I'm making an api call to get some details.
I noticed that when i log in from web and make the api call the JWT from acces token, is having a different scope like: "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin openid profile email"
and another extra field: "version": 2,
but if I make the same process from an iphone the scope is only: "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
and "version": 2, is not present anymore,
My question is: is there a way to setup the scope from my program ? or what should I check next? does it even matter the scope ? I thought it does since practically the token is not the same
The error I encounter is HTTP Response Status Code: 401
Unauthorized - Token may be invalid or expired.
private func loadLoginData(email: String, password: String) -> (succeed: Bool, error: String) {
        //credentialsProvider is nil because the credentials are provided for user pool itself
        let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: nil)
        let pollConfiguration = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolConfiguration(
            clientId: "***",
            clientSecret: "***",
            poolId: "***"
            )
        
        guard let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: "idrive-pool") else {
            return (false, "Failed to initialize user pool")
        }
        
        let user = pool.getUser(email)
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        var loginResult: (Bool, String) = (false, "Unable to connect to server")
        
        let validationData = [ AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType(
            name: "scope", value: "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin openid profile email"
        )]
        
        user.getSession(email, password: password, validationData: validationData).continueWith
        { task in
            if let error = task.error as NSError? {
                loginResult = (false, "Login failed: \(error.userInfo["message"] ?? "Unknown error")")
            } else if let sesion = task.result {
                guard let idToken = sesion.idToken?.tokenString else {
                    loginResult = (false, "Cannot find token id token")
                    semaphore.signal()
                    return nil
                }
                guard let accessToken = sesion.accessToken?.tokenString else {
                    loginResult = (false, "Cannot find acces id token")
                    semaphore.signal()
                    return nil
                }
                guard let refreshToken = sesion.refreshToken?.tokenString else {
                    loginResult = (false, "Cannot find refresh id tokne")
                    semaphore.signal()
                    return nil
                }
                print("accesToken: \(accessToken)")
                let getCompList = ApiCompaniesI5()
                getCompList.sendRequest(with: accessToken, clientId: pollConfiguration.clientId)
                
            }
            semaphore.signal()
            return nil
        }
        semaphore.wait()
        return loginResult
    }

class ApiCompaniesI5 {
    
    private let apiUrl = "https://api-us1.asd.com/companies/list"
    
    func sendRequest(with token: String, clientId: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: apiUrl) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
    
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue(clientId, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-api-key")
        print(request)
        if let headers = request.allHTTPHeaderFields {
            print("Headers:")
            for (key, value) in headers {
                print("\(key): \(value)")
            }
        }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("error:\(error)")
                return
            }
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("HTTP Response Status Code: \(response.statusCode)")
                if response.statusCode == 401 {
                    print("Unauthorized - Token may be invalid or expired.")
                }
            }
            if let data = data {
                if let jsonResponse = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) {
                        print("for data: \(data) \nresponse: \(jsonResponse)")
                }else {
                    print("Failed to parse response data")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

